# How to get count in relation table in yii2 MongoDB Activerecord and sort it?

Tags: mongodb, yii2

I have 2 tables
1) products with fields [_id, name, user_id]
2) users [_id, login]

How can I get Users with products count and sort by products count In \yii\mongodb\ActiveRecord ? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

you can use following...

```
db.products.aggregate(
   [
      {
        $group : {
            totalProducts: { $count: { "user_id" } }
        }
      }
   ]
).sort( { totalProducts: -1 } )
```

for more reference follow the links

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/

Comment: unknown group operator '$count''